# Change image size on JQuery tab slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the exact code from the [bootstrap carousel collection](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/VolV).

But I have a smaller image than the 1200x440 specified. How can I center the image?

I have tried to add an inline `style="display:block"` and creating a class and adjusting the stylesheet, but nothing seems to work. What is the right way to center a smaller image that I do not want to resize?

Comment: Add the code you wrote the demonstrates the problem...

Comment: It is literally the exact same code, but I switched the image source to another image.

What I tried is adding style="width:80%; height:60%;display: block;" and class="img" and added a stylesheet format for .img {display: block}

Comment: so create a jsfiddle/snippet with the relevant images so we can see the problem.

Comment: You didn't specify if you want to center the image vertically, horizontally or both. See the answer below for horizontal alignment.

Comment: Thanks, the answer below worked for me. If you have time, could you please explain to me why the `display: block was` not automatically placing the img in the middle but that the margins had to be adjusted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for the css selector ".carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img" and add the following declaration:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. If you have time, could you please explain to me why the `display: block was` not automatically placing the img in the middle but that the margins had to be adjusted? Sorry, I am still a beginner in web development.

Answer (score 0):

The div class"item" should have the following style:

-- Note this is only if you want the div to have fixed size for all images in the carousel --

```
height: 400px;
width: 1200px;
```

And the img should have:

```
margin: auto;
```